# Inno Setup - Convert Integer 652 to floating point gives 6.52?

Tags: floating-point, inno-setup

This is probably more a Pascal question than an Inno Setup question. How come when I do this:

```
floatnum := 652;
```

The actual value stored in the float is 6.5200000 and not 652.000000?

Update: It's been pointed out that 6.52 is actually 652 which is confusing to me so I guess I should be more specific. Here is some code I have trouble with:

```
floatnum := 305 / 600;
```

I would expect that floatnum would hold close to 0.5083333 but it doesn't, instead holding 5.08333325. That doesn't look right to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show a bit more code?  Converting integer to float (in Innosetup *or* Pascal) does *not* arbitrarily "divide by 100".  There must be something else going on here... IMHO...

Comment: @paul that's the code. I have floatnum declared as `floatnum: Single;` When I view it in the debugger after the assignment it says 6.5200000.

Comment: TLama gave you the correct answer (which, btw, I would *never* have guessed).  It's *NOT* showing you "6.52".  It's showing "6.52 * 10^2"!

Comment: PS: Cool video you might enjoy: [Powers of Ten](http://www.powersof10.com/film)

Comment: @all I didn't realize that. I have marked the answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just missed the whole debugger's value interpratation. See the following screenshot:

[image]

The value of [`6.52000000000000E+0002 is actually 652`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6.52000000000000E%2b0002) what confirms also the next line:

[image]

Comment: I still don't get it. I updated my question. 6.52 should be 6.52 how is it 652?

Comment: If you assign value 652 then it is represented as 6.52 x 10^2.

Comment: This is called [scientific notication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: @Deanna In C I could do this `float floatnum = 652;` and it would show 652.000000. I completely missed the exponent in Inno although it's fairly obvious, since it's right there :)